# php checking upload file if the name exist already

Tags: php

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
$uploadOk = 1;
$FileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
echo "Sorry, $target_file already exists.";
$uploadOk = 0; 
}

//check file size
if ($uploadFile_size > 1) {
echo nl2br("sorry, exceeded file size
\r\n check your file size.
\r\n Error Code: ");
var_dump($_FILES['file']['error']); 
$uploadOk = 0;
}

// check if there is error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo nl2br("sorry, no files are uploaded
\r\n check the file and try again
\r\n Error Code: ");
var_dump($_FILES['file']['error']); 

// if no error
} else { 
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadFile"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir)) {
    echo "your ". basename( $_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"]). " file is successfully uploaded.";
    echo nl2br("\r\n thank you.");
    echo nl2br("\r\n you may close the window.");       
} 
else {
    echo  nl2br("-file upload fail- \r\n Error Code: ");
    var_dump($_FILES['file']['error']); 
    echo nl2br("\r\n \r\n please, check your file one more time.");
}
}
?>
```

Hi, the above is part of my php script and $target_file suppose to refer a file that is selected to be upload onto the server but it keep refers "uploads/" directory.

Since $target_file is referring "uploads/" no matter which file i selected to upload, it keeps generating error that the file is already exist on the server.

The script is copied exactly same from w3school webpage and I am using chrome browser to examine if the script works correctly.

Can someone help me to fix this simple error?  My problem will most likely to be solved if the $target_file can be referred after file that is selected to be uploaded.

Thank you.

Comment: Please don’t use W3Schools. Reason: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: added full php code.

Comment: Heres a question, are you sure that the file actually doesn't exist?

Comment: no, it doesn't exist on uploads directory. I tried with different files but i still gets same error

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching and studying for myself to solve the error and I decided to start over my script from the beginning and the new script work as perfectly as it is coded for.

However, I still don't know what was wrong with the above script.
If anyone, later, captures any errors from my original script feel free to comment me.

Here is my newly created php script for uploading.

p.s. Thanks to those who tried to help me to figure out the error.

```
<?php
$my_folder = "uploads/";
$uploadOk = 1;
$FileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($my_folder . $_FILES['file']['name'])) {
echo 'Sorry,' . $_FILES['file']['name'] . 'already exists.';
$uploadOk = 0; 
}

//check file size
if ($_FILES['file']['size'] > 100000000) {
echo 'Sorry, your file exceeded upload size limit.  Please check your file size and try again'; 
$uploadOk = 0;
}

// check if there is error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo 'NO FILES ARE UPLOADED'; 
} 
else { 
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $my_folder . $_FILES['file']['name'])) {
    echo 'Received file' . $_FILES['file']['name'] . ' with size ' . $_FILES['file']['size'];
} else {
    echo 'Upload failed!';

    var_dump($_FILES['file']['error']);
}
}

?>
```